# Why can't I send a large file to a FAT32 formatted USB Drive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, file-format

Why can't my USB drive accept a large file, as in bigger than **3.50 gb**, when it is formatted in FAT32?

My drive is a (**16 gb**) drive, but when I tried to send an ISO file to it while it was formatted in FAT32, it didn't accept it and showed a message that the file was too large. I reformatted my usb in **NTFS** and sent the ISO file again. This time the file was transferred successfully.

So why didn't it work when it was formatted in FAT32?

Comment: This question should be reopened.  I disagree that it is a duplicate.  The sited "original" question is about how to get around the file size limit, whereas this one was more simply, "why couldn't I transfer the file?" (because there is a size limit).  These questions are closely related, but not duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) especially §FAT32

> The maximum possible size for a file on a FAT32 volume is 4 GiB minus 1 byte or 4,294,967,295 (232 − 1) bytes. This limit is a consequence of the file length entry in the directory table and would also affect huge FAT16 partitions with a sufficient sector size.[1] Large video files, DVD images and databases often exceed this limit.

Comment: Also, see this question for additional ways to get around the problem:
https://superuser.com/questions/440509/getting-around-the-fat32-4gb-file-size-limit